# nginx 502 bad gateway with nodejs

Tags: nginx, node.js, 502

i am an student who is working on a nodejs + nginx project taht i didn't start,  so im not sure what is going on.... when i try accessing to my website,  i am recibing a 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.12.2 error.

i have been trying to solve it with the answers of other similar question but the problem is still there, i think there is something wrong with the configuration, but im not sure what it is.

the nginx.conf file is as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

//var http = require('http');
var app = require('../app/app');
var config = require('../config/config');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
*/
process.env.PORT = config.port;
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT);
//app.set('port', port);
app.listen(port , function () {
console.log('App listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
});
/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
//var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

//server.listen(port);
//server.on('error', onError);
//server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */
function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */
/* function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }
    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + port
        : 'Port ' + port;
    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
} */

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */
/* function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    console.log('Express server listening on port: %d, in %s mode', 
app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
} */
```

also i have already checked the logs

```
2018/11/26 09:32:14 [error] 974#0: *7094 connect() failed (111: Connection 
refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 189.183.151.200, server: 
mexcx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: 
"67.227.198.57"
```

hope you can help me on understanding what is going on, cause at the beginig it was working just fine, i was doing some changes on the code, i restart the server and i got the problem

Comment: You have not provided enough information to give you anything but the general advice in the linked question. If you want help with a specific problem, you will need to provide sufficient information about the problem you are having. For instance, you need to check everything in the linked question, and report on what the results were.